# DJIGlobalService must extend android.app.Service

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I got this error (*Error:(58, 32) `DJIGlobalService` must extend android.app.Service*) while compiling a Java Android app based on a DJI sample from
https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-UXSDKDemo/tree/master

Basically it complains for this line of code which is the original from the repository